# Faster way to check if entry exists in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my app when data is synced i can get 20k entries (from given timestamp) from the server that should be synced to the local device. For every entry i try to fetch it (if it exist already) and if doesn't i create new. The problem is that the whole operation is too slow - for 20k on iphone 5 is 10+ mins. Another solution that i though is to delete all entries from the given timestamp and create new entries for all returned entries and there will be no need to perform fetch for every single entry ? If someone have any advice will be nice. Here is sample code for the current state:

```
    var logEntryToUpdate:LogEntry!
    if let savedEntry = CoreDataRequestHelper.getLogEntryByID(inputID: inputID, fetchAsync: true) {
        logEntryToUpdate = savedEntry
    } else {
        logEntryToUpdate = LogEntry(entity: logEntryEntity!, insertInto: CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.saveManagedObjectContext)
    }
    logEntryToUpdate.populateWithSyncedData(data: row, startCol: 1)
```

Here is the actual request method:

```
class func getLogEntryByID(inputID:Int64, fetchAsync:Bool) ->LogEntry? {

    let logEntryRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "LogEntry")
    logEntryRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "inputId == %@", NSNumber(value: inputID as Int64))
    logEntryRequest.fetchLimit = 1

    do {
        let mocToFetch = fetchAsync ? CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.saveManagedObjectContext : CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
        if let fetchResults = try mocToFetch.fetch(logEntryRequest) as? [LogEntry] {
            if ( fetchResults.count > 0 ) {
                return fetchResults[0]
            }
            return nil
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("Error fetching Log Entries by inputID from core data !!! \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    return nil

}
```

Another thing that i tried is to check the count for specific request but again is too slow.

```
class func doesLogEntryExist(inputID:Int64, fetchAsync:Bool) ->Bool {

    let logEntryRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "LogEntry")
    logEntryRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "inputId == %@", NSNumber(value: inputID as Int64))
    //logEntryRequest.resultType = .countResultType
    logEntryRequest.fetchLimit = 1

    do {
        let mocToFetch = fetchAsync ? CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.saveManagedObjectContext : CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
        let count = try mocToFetch.count(for: logEntryRequest)
        if ( count > 0 ) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("Error fetching Log Entries by inputID from core data !!! \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    return false

}
```

Comment: Instead of fetching each potential match, one at a time, why don't you load all of the existing ids (or all since the timestamp,if you have that field in core data) into an array or set.. 20,000 8 byte identifiers is only 160KB and you can search in memory much quicker than individual fetches from a large dataset.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you! Your method made my imports scream! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether fetching the instance or getting the count, you're still doing one fetch request per incoming record. That's going to be slow, and your code will be spending almost all of its time performing fetches.

One improvement is to batch up the records to reduce the number of fetches. Get multiple record IDs into an array, and then fetch all of them at once with a predicate like

```
NSPredicate(format: "inputId IN %@", inputIdArray)
```

Then go through the results of the fetch to see which IDs were found. Accumulate 50 or 100 IDs in the array, and you'll reduce the number of fetches by 50x or 100x.

Deleting all the entries for the timestamp and then re-inserting them might be good, but it's hard to predict. You'll have to insert all 20,000. Is that faster or slower than reducing the number of fetches? It's impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on  [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11)'s comment, I came up with the following method to evaluate `Structs` being imported into Core Data.

In my example, I have a class where I store search terms. Within the search class, create a predicate which describes the values of the stuff within my array of structs.

```
func importToCoreData(dataToEvaluateArray: [YourDataStruct]) {
    // This is what Paul described in his comment
    let newDataToEvaluate = Set(dataToEvaluateArray.map{$0.id})
    let recordsInCoreData = getIdSetForCurrentPredicate()
    let newRecords = newDataToEvaluate.subtracting(recordsInCoreData)
    // create an empty array
    var itemsToImportArray: [YourDataStruct] = []

    // and dump records with ids contained in newRecords into it
    dataToEvaluateArray.forEach{ record in
      if newRecords.contains(record.id) {
        itemsToImportArray.append(record)
      }
    }

    // THEN, import if you need to
    itemsToImportArray.forEach { struct in
        // set up your entity, properties, etc.
    }

    // Once it's imported, save
    // You can save each time you import a record, but it'll go faster if you do it once.
    do {
        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error {
        self.delegate?.errorAlert(error.localizedDescription, sender: self)
    }

    self.delegate?.updateFetchedResultsController()
}
```

To instantiate `recordsInCoreData`, I created this method, which returns a Set of unique identifiers that exist in the `managedObjectContext`:

```
  func getIdSetForCurrentPredicate() -> Set<String> {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "YourEntity")
    // searchQuery is a class I created with a computed property for a creating a predicate. You'll need to write your own predicate
    fetchRequest.predicate = searchQuery.predicate

    var existingIds: [YourEntity] = []

    do {
      existingIds = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [YourEntity]
    } catch let error {
      delegate?.errorAlert(error.localizedDescription, sender: self)
    }

    return Set<String>(existingIds.map{$0.id})
  }
```